# Can't get htaccess to rewrite subdirectory URLs with wordpress in the root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've tried several variations to get this to work. Wordpress is in the root and I have a subdirectory /jobs/ that I am trying to rewrite the query string. Something from wordpress just won't let it happen.

I am trying to go from /jobs/jobs.php?q=keyword&l=city,state to /jobs/keyword/state/city/

I've tried htaccess in the subdirectory and root. Here's my latest iteration in the root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite rules for the /jobs/ folder
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /jobs/jobs.php?q=$1&l=$3,+$2 [NC,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
# Default rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>



# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried using this variation for the jobs rewrite in root and the subdirectory:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+)&l=([^&]+),([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^jobs/jobs\.php$ /jobs/%1/%3/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You are missing the `L` flag on that rule.

Comment: `L` isn't the issue.  I've tried that too.

Comment: "Something from wordpress just won't let it happen" - So what does happen exactly? You are presumably requesting a URL of the form `/jobs/keyword/state/city/`? Is `jobs.php` outside of WordPress? Why do you have `+` (encoded _space_) in the query string of the _substitution_?

Comment: _"I've also tried"_ - both of those things are the opposite of each other. The rewrite your have in your .htaccess, is the direction _from_ the pretty external URL, to the internal one with the query string parameters. What you have shown below, is the redirect from the query string parameter URL, to the pretty version. So which of the two are you having problems with in particular?